# Django model field choices - wouldn't a dict be better?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Given a field;

```
domain_status_choices = (
    (1,'Live')
    (2,'Offline')
    (3,'Dev')
)
status = models.SmallIntegerField( choices=domain_status_choices )
```

I know I can get and set numeric representation and use `get_status_display()` to get the text label. But if a user posts `status=Offline` how can I get the numeric value in order to save it? I'd also like to be able to validate that numbers or text values are in the list.

To me it makes more sense to use a dict. Here's my current method;

```
domain_status_choices = {
    1: 'Live',
    2: 'Offline',
    3: 'Dev',
}
status = models.SmallIntegerField( choices=domain_status_choices.iteritems() )
...
if input1 not in domain_status_choices.keys(): print "invalid"
if input2 not in domain_status_choices.items(): print "invalid"
status = [k for k, v in domain_status_choices.iteritems() if v == input3][0]
```

Is there a better way? Why is a tuple of tuples usually used?

Comment: Have you tried using collections.OrderedDict for this use case? (To preserve order of options.) http://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the keys of a dict are not guaranteed to be sorted (unless you use `OrderedDict` obviously). That is, you "might" get "Offline", "Dev", "Live" choices with your version.

Implementation note on [dict.items](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

Comment: Here's a thought, in my case with numeric keys I could use a list? (not a list of tuples)

Or, if I'm not worried about the order I could stick with this method.

Comment: Thanks to how Python works, you're free to construct whatever you pass to a Field's `choices` however you want. If you primarily use the choices in some other manner, I don't see anything wrong with converting that list/dict/whatever only when passing it to `<whatever>Field(choices=)` (i.e. if `iteritems` works for you, then that's fine). The point is simply: Django assumes that the order of choices should not be arbitrary.

Comment: "Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6."

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment on @vicvicvic's answer:

```
t = [ 'Live', 'Offline', 'Dev', ]
status = models.SmallIntegerField( choices=[(i,t[i]) for i in range(len(t))] )
...
if not 0 <= int(input1) < len(t): print "invalid"
if input2 not in t: print "invalid"
status = t.index(input2)
```

Comment: Use enumerate to up the pythonicity : `[(i,v) for i,v in enumerate(t)]`

Comment: What about `just enumerate(t)`